# String.Substring Method (Int32, Int32) throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, winforms, substring, argumentexception

I have a string where the first 5 characters are never empty and from char 6 to the end data is variable leght. Something like this:

```
string inData = comPort1.ReadExisting();
//Console.WriteLine("inData: " + inData);
string origMsg = inData.Substring(4, 1);
//Console.WriteLine("origMsg: " + origMsg);
string seAnex = inData.Substring(5, 15);           // ArgumentOutOfRangeException
inData = inData.Substring(5, inData.Length - 8);
//Console.WriteLine("new inData: " + inData);

if (seAnex == "some_text_15_ch")
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```

**Output:**

```
inData: {1112Test}
origMsg: 2
new inData: Test
```

This code throws a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string`. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx

Comment: The problem: `startIndex cannot be larger than length of string`. What are you confused about?

Comment: Are you _sure_ that your input is always at least 5 characters long? Run it in debugging or output when it fails. (also, are you trimming whitespace? Perhaps that is what's throwing it off. Your initial values are length 5 or more, then you trim reducing its length.)

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I did. Lengh: "The number of characters in the substring." I have always a char in that position.

Comment: @mafap Then `inData` is not what you're saying it is. Do you know how to use your debugger? Set some breakpoints and verify what `inData` is   right before you use `Substring`

Comment: @mafap: Can you show us the exact text that this is failing for? As in, make a simple reproducible case with an input text, these 3 (or fewer) commands, which we can then copy/paste and test for ourselves.

Comment: @tnw If you look at my code you can see what's before I use Substring. And yes, I did use the debugger.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair `"test"` will throw the exception. Can you repost your answer?

Comment: @mafap No. You're misunderstanding. It's not the code I'm interested in, its the *value* of `inData` as you call `inData.Substring(4, 1);`. It simply cannot be what you say it is if it's throwing that exception. Are you *sure* that's the line that's throwing the exception?

Comment: I am confused how you can report the line "origMsg: 2" when you say the exception occurred on that line. In other words if the exception occurs, how did you get the output?

Comment: No way you've debugged this properly. I just tested this with exactly the string for `inData` you posted and got no exceptions. Additionally, `origMsg` is *not* 2, it is `T`, and the new `inData` is `his is just a simple t`. *AGAIN*, you need to tell us what the *actual* value of `inData` is.

Comment: origMsg IS 2. The { braces are part of the string

Comment: @tnw sorry, you were correct. Fixed with the line that throws the exception.

Comment: @mafap Still unable to reproduce, with braces surrounding the `inData` string and without. Replace `string inData = comPort1.ReadExisting();` with `string inData = "{1112This is just a simple test}";` and I *guarantee* you will not get an exception. The value you claim `inData` to be originally is simply incorrect.

Comment: @tnw If I replace `string inData = "{1112This is just a simple test}";` with `string inData = "{1112test}";` this will fail. `inData` is created by DataReceived Event, just when I receive data with this format, I think.

Comment: @mafap: My answer was wrong, I was mistaken with some behaviour. But if you input "test", that's 4 characters long and will fail. But you state that you do not have any inputs that have length 4 or less.

Comment: @mafap OK, well for the 4th time, you need to find out what `inData` is. Your code simply won't throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` with the value you provided.

Comment: try adding this test before you call substring: if (inData.Length < 4) throw new Exception("THIS SHOULD NOT HAPPEN");

Comment: [See this paste](http://pastebin.com/kRNgMKZe) and pop that into a console application. There are no exceptions generated whatsoever which is why I am so insistent on re-verifying the value of `inData`.

Comment: @WeylandYutani nothing happened, so inData.Lenght > 4

Comment: How did you determine origMsg equal "2" if an exception occurred BEFORE origMsg was populated?

Comment: "nothing happened, so inData.Lenght > 4" . Did you get the ArgumentOutOfRangeException though?

Comment: @tnw Before that line, inData = null , after `{1112This is just a simple test}`. With `{1112test}` the exception happens.

Comment: @WeylandYutani I didn't. Check the edit, the exception is in `seAnex`.

Comment: string seAnex = inData.Substring(5, 15); <--- inData has to be at least 21 in length for that to work

Comment: With `{1112test}` of course it fails. `inData.Substring(5, 15);` is trying to return the 15 characters following the 5th character in the string. There aren't even 15 characters in the entire string. What are you expecting to happen??? **READ THE DOCUMENTATION**.

Comment: I've had this trouble in the past. The problem is that substring is unkind, it doesn't use intelligence. it does exactly what you tell it to and if the input string is too large or small it throws an exception.

Comment: I also suspect you've copied the wrong exception as well. You're probably getting `Index and length must refer to a location within the string.`. Please, pay some more attention and include correct information with your post. If you'd posted the right value for `inData` this would have been solved ages ago.

Comment: @tnw I did read the Documentation, I just realized that the exception was being throw in another line. The question is still how can I solve that since I have to use that value in my if-else statment.

Comment: You can use inData.Substring(5) to read all the characters from the 5th position. If you don't specify the length parameter, substring will read all the characters to the end of the string.

Comment: oops i forgot about the } bracket at the end of your strings. Try indata.Substring(5, indata.Length - 6) instead. That'll get all the characters from the 5th index to the last but one character.

Comment: @WeylandYutani this worked with `inData.Substring(5, inData.Length - 8);`. inData is at least = `"{1112}\r\n"`

Answer (score 2):

```
string origMsg = inData.Substring(4, 1);
```

"startIndex cannot be larger than length of string"

in other words,

4 cannot be larger than length of inData

4 is larger than length of inData

**inData.Length is less than 4**

Comment: pretty sound logic to me

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what do you want to do with your code. But, if just to resolve the exception. You can fix like this:

```
        string inData = comPort1.ReadExisting();
        //Console.WriteLine("inData: " + inData);
        if (inData.Length >= 5)
        {
            string origMsg = inData.Substring(4, 1);
            //Console.WriteLine("origMsg: " + origMsg);
            //string seAnex = inData.Substring(5, 15);           // ArgumentOutOfRangeException
            string seAnex = inData.Substring(5, inData.Length - 5);
            //inData = inData.Substring(5, inData.Length - 8);
            //Console.WriteLine("new inData: " + inData);

            if (seAnex == "some_text_15_ch")
            {
                //...
            }
            else
            {
                //...
            }
        }
```

I guess your purpose can be get data information from a message have format like `"{111abcxzy}"` in a long data string `"{111abcxzy}{111abcxzy}{..."` that received from COM communication ?

Comment: Yes, something like that but it's solved now. Like I said in my last comment this worked with `inData.Substring(5, inData.Length - 8);`, inData is at least equal to `"{1112}\r\n"`. For the if-else statment I used `inData.StartsWith("some_text_15_ch")`.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet that you do not have the string value you say that you do. If it were in fact 5+ characters long, you would not have and ArgumentOutOfRange exception when you call SubString(4,1) on it. Print out the value or inspect it in the debugger to confirm